# Implicit operators and class hierarchies

Tags: c#

I have the following class hierarchy.

```
public abstract class ResourceBase { }

public abstract class WebResourceBase : ResourceBase  {
  public ResourceBase LocalPath { get; set; }
  public ResourceBase FtpPath { get; set; }
}

public class JavaScript : WebResourceBase { }
```

What I would like to do is have a declaration like so.

```
new JavaScript() {
  LocalPath = "/path/goes/here/1.js",
  FtpPath = "ftp://path/goes/here/1.js"
}
```

The obvious answer here would be to use implicit operators but the problem is that I want to assign a derived type to those properties which is the same as the declared type so `LocalPath` and `FtpPath` would be of type `JavaScript`.

I'd like my solution to be more flexible than what I have at the moment. This code just makes my skin crawl. Was hoping there was a way using reflection and I have tried looking for information using the `StackTrace` class but no luck. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

```
public abstract class ResourceBase { 
  public static implicit operator ResourceBase(string path) {
            if (path.EndsWith(".js"))
                return new JavaScript(path);
            // etc...
  }
}
```

Comment: Does `WebResourceBase` should be derived from `ResourceBase`?

Comment: i would implement an explicit function to map this rather than use implicit operators. this will make maintaining and understanding the code more difficult over the life of the project.

Comment: @Vince Sorry, I see the problem now. I'll amend my answer.

Comment: If the base class declared an abstract method that took in a string (`path`) and returned a `ResourceBase`, then the `JavaScript` class could implement that method by returning `new JavaScript(path);`, and so on.

Comment: Or maybe you should simply let your `JavaScript` class (and other derived classes) have a constructor that takes two string arguments. Then you could do the stuff in the constructor. You don't *have* to use "object initializers"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<sub>This assumes that `WebResourceBase` is actually meant to inherit `ResourceBase`.</sub>

You won't be able to make the implicit operator look much nicer, unfortunately - generics won't work here.

---

**Alternative: Generics to constrain ResourceBase**

Now that I've re-read it and understand what you're after, one option is to amend your classes to include a generic parameter referencing derived classes (sort of like a self-reference):

```
public abstract class ResourceBase 
{ }

public abstract class WebResourceBase<T> : ResourceBase
    where T : WebResourceBase<T>
{
    public T LocalPath { get; set; }
    public T FtpPath { get; set; }
}

public class JavaScript : WebResourceBase<JavaScript> 
{ 
}
```

Then you will see that in `JavaScript`, the properties `LocalPath` and `FtpPath` are now of type `JavaScript` also.

Now your assignment will *only* accept `JavaScript` types:

```
new JavaScript() 
{
    LocalPath = new JavaScript("/path/goes/here/1.js"),
    FtpPath = new JavaScript("ftp://path/goes/here/1.js")
}
```

The benefit of this approach is it will constrain the base properties to be of the current type or more derived, not less derived.

---

**Alternative: Explicit parsing instead of `implicit` operator**

If you need to leave the `LocalPath` and `FtpPath` variables as `ResourceBase`, or otherwise cannot use generics here, your implicit operator will start to get confusing. Better to provide something explicit like a static method:

```
new JavaScript() 
{
    LocalPath = JavaScript.Parse("/path/goes/here/1.js"),
    FtpPath = JavaScript.Parse("ftp://path/goes/here/1.js")
}

class JavaScript
{
    public static ResourceBase Parse(string s)
    {
        if (path.EndsWith(".js"))
            return new JavaScript(path);

        throw new Exception();
    }
}
```

---

**Alternative: Class hierarchy parsing instead of `implicit` operator**

Bake the concept of consuming strings into the types via constructors and make the properties public read-only:

```
public abstract class ResourceBase
{ }

public abstract class WebResourceBase
{
    public ResourceBase LocalPath { get; private set; }
    public ResourceBase FtpPath { get; private set; }

    protected abstract ResourceBase ParseLocalPath(string s);
    protected abstract ResourceBase ParseFtpPath(string s);
}

public class JavaScript : WebResourceBase<JavaScript> 
{ 
    protected override ResourceBase ParseLocalPath(string s)
    {
        // etc.
    } 
    protected override ResourceBase ParseFtpPath(string s)
    {
        // etc.
    } 
}
```

---

To be honest, most of this seems a little overkill just to get two properties set as a particular type from a string, you have loads of options - even the implicit operator will work.

Pick the one that is easiest to understand. Operator overloading tends to be somewhat hidden unless you go digging for it.

Answer (score 1):

<sub>I too assume that `WebResourceBase` is supposed to inherit from `ResourceBase`</sub>

Have a `protected` mapping mechanism on the base class that derived classes can subscribe themselves to:

```
public abstract class ResourceBase
{
    // Records how to make a ResourceBase from a string, 
    // on a per-extension basis
    private static Dictionary<string, Func<string, ResourceBase>> constructorMap
        = new Dictionary<string, Func<string, ResourceBase>>();

    // Allows a derived type to subscribe itself
    protected static void Subscribe(
        string extension, 
        Func<string, ResourceBase> ctor)
    {
        if (constructorMap.ContainsKey(extension))
            throw new Exception("nuh uh");

        constructorMap.Add(extension, ctor);
    }

    // Given a string, finds out who has signed up to deal with it,
    // and has them deal with it
    public static implicit operator ResourceBase(string s)
    {
        // Find a matching extension
        var matches = constructorMap.Where(kvp => s.EndsWith(kvp.Key)).ToList();

        switch (matches.Count)
        {
            case 0:
                throw new Exception(
                  string.Format("Don't know how to make {0} into a ResourceBase",
                                s));
            case 1:
                return matches.Single().Value(s);
            default:
                throw new Exception(string.Format(
                  "More than one possibility for making {0} into a ResourceBase",
                  s));
        }
    }
}
```

The intermediate type is largely unchanged, but with some type checking that I can't work out how to enforce at compile time:

```
public abstract class WebResourceBase : ResourceBase
{
    private ResourceBase localPath;
    public ResourceBase LocalPath
    {
        get { return localPath; }
        set
        {
            if (value.GetType() != GetType())
            {
                throw new Exception("Naughty");
            }
            localPath = value;
        }
    }        

    private ResourceBase ftpPath;
    public ResourceBase FtpPath
    {
        get { return ftpPath; }
        set
        {
            if (value.GetType() != GetType())
            {
                throw new Exception("Naughty");
            }
            ftpPath = value;
        }
    }
}
```

The concrete types look like this:

```
public class JavaScript : WebResourceBase
{
    public JavaScript()
    {

    }
    private JavaScript(string s)
    {
    }

    static JavaScript()
    {
        Subscribe("js", s => (ResourceBase)new JavaScript(s));
    }
}
```

Usage is as you specified:

```
        var js = new JavaScript
        {
            LocalPath = "hello.js",
            FtpPath = "hello.js"
        };
```

Note that despite the `ResourceBase` in the signature of `constructorMap` and `Subscribe`, after the above statement `LocalPath` and `FtpPath` **are** `JavaScript` objects.

Answer (score 0):

I would just add an extra layer of indirection to the process (it's amazing how often that's a good answer for design questions ;) ).

I would either add a new constructor that takes two string parameters, add two additional string properties, or both.  (I'll assume you're just adding two new string properties from here on; you can extrapolate from there.)

If you add a new property: `JavaScriptLocalPath` it can, in it's set method, convert the string into a derived type of `ResourceBase` specific to `JavaScript` and the set the `LocationPath` property using that result.  I assume it's get method can also extract that string out of the `ResourceBase` (so that you don't need to bother storing the `string` as well).

Answer (score 0):

Here's my idea:

```
public abstract class WebResourceBase {
  public ResourceBase LocalPath { get; set; }
  public ResourceBase FtpPath { get; set; }

  protected abstract ResourceBase ConvertFromString(string path);
  public string LocalPathStr { set { LocalPath = ConvertFromString(value); } }
  public string FtpPathStr { set { FtpPath = ConvertFromString(value); } }
}
```

Could probably be improved.